# Angular view doesn't update when the model object is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have a view item that looks like this:

```
 <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64, {{vm.scanResult.items[0].frontImage}}" alt="" />
```

When the VM contains items[0].frontImage, i have no problem.  The problem occurs when my object doesn't have a items[0].frontImage node.  The previous image remains..

How do I ensure that if the node doesn't exist, I get no image in the View?

Comment: `{{vm.scanResult.items[0].frontImage || ''}}`?

Comment: That should do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting as an answer as well:

`{{vm.scanResult.items[0].frontImage || ''}}`

should do the trick.

Comment: A better question would be, why isn't that handled internally in the VM engine.  It seems counter intuitive,  Or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: It gives you more control/option. I wouldn't say it's the best example, but you could do something like `<img ng-src="{{vm.user.profileImage || vm.defaultImage}}">`. Obviously you could handle this in the controller (or service), but sometimes it's just easier to do it like this.